# Placing and Input element next to a button element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add an input element next to a drop down menu so that when the drop down menu open it does not cover the input. However, even after setting the display property of the input box to inline-block it still appears below the dropdown button element. May i please have some assistance in figuring out why this is happening and what may be a solution? I tried to use the display property and set it to inline-block but it does not work.

```css
div.metric.two {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    max-width: 450px;
    width:100%;
}

.workout-header {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropbtn {
    display:flex;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: var(--darker);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  .dropbtn::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
  }
  
  /* Style the dropdown content */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: var(--darker);
  }
  
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: var(--dark);
  }

  .exercise-input {
    display:inline-block;
    /* top:0; */
    /* left: calc(100% +10px); */
    background-color: var(--dark);
    margin-left: 4px;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    color:var(--light-gray)
  }
```

```html
<div class="metric two">
  <div class="workout-header">
    <h2 class="title_workouts">Workouts</h2>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Workout Type</button>
      <div id="workoutsDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Weight Training ️</a>
        <a href="#">Cardio </a>
        <a href="#">Calisthenics </a>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="exercise-input" class="exercise-input" placeholder="Exercise"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also describe the effect you want to achieve, how it is different from the way the snippet is behaving, and why you have chosen to implement it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like to have a working dropdown list next to an input field.
This answer just aimed to solve the overlapping problem.

Change both the dropdown button and input field to be `inline-block`, such to be side by side. The content set to `block` such that placed below.

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  ......
}
.exercise-input {
  display: inline-block;
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list group.

```css
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
       
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        min-width: 200px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: var(--dark);
        margin-left: 4px;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        color:var(--light-gray)
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 200px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
       
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
    
    .exercise-input {
    display:inline-block;
    /* top:0; */
    /* left: calc(100% +10px); */
    background-color: var(--dark);
    margin-left: 4px;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    color:var(--light-gray)
  }
```

```html
<div class="metric two">
  <div class="workout-header">
    <h2 class="title_workouts">Workouts</h2>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
     <li> <input type="text" name="exercise-input" class="exercise-input" placeholder="Exercise"/>
        </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Workout Type &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Weight Training ️</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cardio </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calisthenics </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```